# @import-ed .scss files and Sprockets 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sass, sprockets

This is maybe too early to get good answers, but here we go: I have a test Rails project, with `assets/` directory that looks something like this:

```
config/
  manifest.js
images/
javascripts/
  application.js
stylesheets/
  _base.scss
  _reset.scss
  _theme.scss
  _variables.scss
  application.scss
```

The manifest file looks like this:

```
// JS and CSS bundles
//= link_tree ../javascripts .js
//= link_tree ../stylesheets .css

// Images so that views can link to them
//= link_tree ../images
```

And the `application.scss` like this:

```
@import "reset";
@import "variables";
@import "base";
@import "theme";
```

`_base.scss` and `_theme.scss` both make use of variables defined in the `_variables.scss` file.

What I *want* it to do is just compile `application.scss` as normal, but it fails because it doesn't think the variables are defined; this is reasonable, I'm linking as a tree, so [I assume] it's compiling each file individually, and the variables are not available to the two files at that point in time.

So I try `link ../stylesheets/application.css` instead of the tree, and I get the error message `couldn't find file '../stylesheets/application.css' under '/Users/danielcouper/Projects/myproject/app/assets/config'`; *ie* it *seems* to be looking in entirely the wrong place, or there are different (undocumented) rules regarding filepaths depending on whether you use `link` or `link_tree`.

If I move `manifest.js` out from the `assets/config/` directory to `assets/` to get the relative paths working, as described in [the Sprockets upgrading notes](https://github.com/rails/sprockets/blob/master/UPGRADING.md), I get an error telling me that there is no manifest file under `assets/config/`.

The documentation is [understandably] super sparse at the minute; the only useful thing I've read was at http://eileencodes.com/posts/the-sprockets-4-manifest/, which allowed me to get to this point

Comment: I'm having the same issue, couldn't find an answer to it too. I'm manually importing needed files everywhere currently.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `link_tree`, link tree will import all the files in the tree. If you only want one application.css file use this:

```
link application.scss
```

This way sprockets will start at that file and sass will do the imports.